# How to structure CRUD file structure with react and react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So, I have a dashboard with a sidebar and links to multiple entities: `customers`, `products`, `users`, etc. Every entity has common crud operations like create, update, list and view. What are some best practices around the file structure for nested routes?

src/components/CustomersRoute ?

src/routes/customers/CustomersRoute ?

src/routes/customers/index ?

I know that whatever feels right is usually the best way, but I just want to know how experienced react programmers structure this kind of things.